# Multiple array manipulation in Numpy

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

A= [[4,0,1],
    [8,0,1]]

B = [[4,1,1],
     [8,0,1]]

Output= [[4,0,1],
         [8,0,1]]

I have 2 numpy arrays A and B and I want to get an output nparray which is like an XOR of the values in the 2 original array i.e. if the cells are same, keep the value, if they are different, put a 0 there. What is the best way to do this?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Kind of a poor example, isn't it?  Output is the same as `A`.

Answer (score 2):

[`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) might be a good fit here -

```
np.where(A == B,A,0)
```

Basically with the three input format : `np.where(mask,array1,array2)`, it selects elements from `array1` or `array2` if the corresponding elements in the `mask` are `True` or `False` respectively. So, in our case with `np.where(A == B,A,0)`, the mask `A==B` when `True` selects elements from `A`, which would be the same as `B`, otherwise sets to `0`.

The same effect could also be brought in with elementwise multiplication between the mask `A==B` and `A`, like so -

```
A*(A==B)
```

Sample run -

```
In [24]: A
Out[24]: 
array([[4, 5, 1],
       [8, 0, 1]])

In [25]: B
Out[25]: 
array([[4, 1, 1],
       [8, 0, 1]])

In [26]: np.where(A == B,A,0)
Out[26]: 
array([[4, 0, 1],
       [8, 0, 1]])

In [27]: A*(A==B)
Out[27]: 
array([[4, 0, 1],
       [8, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Divakar and hpaulj for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

While `where` is a nice one-liner, you should learn how to do this with simple boolean masking.

```
In [9]: A= np.array([[4,0,1], [8,0,1]])
In [10]: B =np.array( [[4,1,1], [8,0,1]])
```

A boolean array showing where the elements don't match

```
In [11]: A!=B
Out[11]: 
array([[False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Use that to modify a copy of `A`:

```
In [12]: C=A.copy()
In [13]: C[A!=B]=0
In [14]: C
Out[14]: 
array([[4, 0, 1],
       [8, 0, 1]])
```

For clarity, let's insert a different value, -1:

```
In [15]: C[A!=B]=-1
In [16]: C
Out[16]: 
array([[ 4, -1,  1],
       [ 8,  0,  1]])
```