# numpy array where vectorized version

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading about vectorized expressions in cheat sheet. It is mentioned as below

Vectorized expressions

np.where(cond, x, y) is a vectorized version of the expression ‘x if condition else y’

example:

```
np.where([True, False], [1, 2], [2, 3]) => ndarray (1, 3)
```

I am not able understand above example. My understanding is that we should have expression but here we have list of [True, False].

Request to explain in break up and how we got output of ndarray(1,3)

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the official docs : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html? Which specific part are you stuck with on its explanation?

Comment: my question is how do we go output ndarray(1,3) in above example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply function to masked numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421913/). One more : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188508

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally use `np.where` to convert a boolean array to an index array. Consider this example:

```
In [12]: a = np.random.rand((10))

In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
array([ 0.80785098,  0.49922039,  0.02018482,  0.69514821,  0.87127179,
        0.23235574,  0.73199572,  0.79935066,  0.46667908,  0.11330817])

In [14]: bool_array = a > 0.5

In [15]: bool_array
Out[15]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [16]: np.where(bool_array)
Out[16]: (array([0, 3, 4, 6, 7]),)
```

---

**Explanation of your example.** For every value in `cond`: if `True`, pick value from `x`, otherwise pick value from `y`.

```
cond: [True, False]
x   : [1, 2]
y   : [2, 3]

Result:
cond[0] == True  -> out[0] == x[0]
cond[1] == False -> out[1] == y[1]
out == [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The array `[True, False]` is what would be produced by an expression like `x<y` where `x=np.array([1,1])` and `y=np.array([2,0])`. So `cond` is a boolean array that is often the result of an expression like the previous one. 
An example of a more real-world-ish usage would therfore be :

```
np.where(x<y, [1, 2], [2, 3])
```